# is there a maximum number of items a user can have in an order in ibm commerce

Tags: java, e-commerce, websphere

IBM Websphere Commerce 6

I have a user that has over 500 unique items in a single order. These are OrderItems that are associated with an ORDERS table in IBM DB2.

Apparently they can not load the shopping list? I was wondering if there was an upper limit on the number of items that a order could have or what the number would be when the list start to have performance problems.

I have not found any documentation on that. I have found documentation on limiting the number of items in a shopping list, and adding performance improvements for large list but they do not define what a large list is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the link below ,it describes how to achieve the same in wcs 7 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/tasks/toscfgbounds.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of an upper limit but I don't know what it is.  I would contact IBM Software Support and they can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hitting the OrderItemAdd URL with these items, yes you will have a limitation since the query string is limited for a HTTP GET request (which ofcource can be configured at the web server configurations)
There is a WebSphere Commerce configuration on the maximum number of order items that can be added to cart at the installation level as well as at a contract level. You can verify if your scenario doesn't fall there.